# Javascript: Change 'choose folder' to specific location

Tags: javascript, directory, applescript, photoshop, finder

I have a javascript I found but it starts with having the user choose a folder where it will grab files. I want to create a watch folder so I want to tell the javascript the folder to grab the files from, not let the user choose. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I know applescript but cannot grasp javascript. Thank you!

Here is what I believe the area I need to change:

```js
function main() {
   // user settings
   var prefs = new Object();
   prefs.sourceFolder         = '/Volumes/SERVER_RAID/•Current/MPC';  // default browse location (default: '~')
   prefs.removeFileExtensions = true; // remove filename extensions for imported layers (default: true)
   prefs.savePrompt           = true; // display save prompt after import is complete (default: false)
   prefs.closeAfterSave       = true; // close import document after saving (default: false)

   // prompt for source folder
   var sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog('Where are the Front and Back files?', Folder(prefs.sourceFolder));

   // ensure the source folder is valid
   if (!sourceFolder) {
      return;
   }
   else if (!sourceFolder.exists) {
      alert('Source folder not found.', 'Script Stopped', true);
      return;
   }

   // add source folder to user settings
   prefs.sourceFolder = sourceFolder;

   // get a list of files
   var fileArray = getFiles(prefs.sourceFolder);

   // if files were found, proceed with import
   if (fileArray.length) {
      importFolderAsLayers(fileArray, prefs);
   }
   // otherwise, diplay message
   else {
      alert("The selected folder doesn't contain any recognized images.", 'No Files Found', false);
   }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// getFiles - get all files within the specified source
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getFiles(sourceFolder) {
   // declare local variables
   var fileArray = new Array();
   var extRE = /\.(?:png)$/i;

   // get all files in source folder
   var docs = sourceFolder.getFiles();
   var len = docs.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var doc = docs[i];

      // only match files (not folders)
      if (doc instanceof File) {
         // store all recognized files into an array
         var docName = doc.name;
         if (docName.match(extRE)) {
            fileArray.push(doc);
         }
      }
   }

   // return file array
   return fileArray;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I understand I could use an input file function but have not idea where it would go or what it would replace.

Comment: Not in a cross-browser, cross-platform manner, no.

Comment: ok...just don't understand I guess. Seems like it would be a simple thing. Instead of having the user give it the directory to use you'd think I could just tell it the directory to use beforehand. This would be a MAC only application. Instead of using the Folder.selectDialog I could just feed it the directory I want to use.

Comment: Hold on, Folder.selectDialog... Is this a web application or something else?

Comment: It's just a little script application to automate some things in a Photoshop workflow on a MAC. Not a web application. Script grabs files in a folder and opens them as layers in a photoshop document. Just want to give it the directory of a folder where the images will be, not throw up a dialog box that the user needs to interact with. Want to make it more 'hands off'.

Comment: I honestly don't know enough about Javascript to say. I found this javascript file online. it's a .jsx file. I built an applescript to run it because it does something I cannot do using applescript. After the javascript runs, the applescript finishes the process. I've edited the javascript to customize it a little but can't figure out this part.

Comment: Excellent answer by RobC, although, looking at his code, I am pretty confident that you could have just done that with AppleScript, given that you had to use AppleScript to run the JavaScript.

Comment: Agreed, it probably is possible. I just happened to find this one that did everything I needed (except for the input file part) and I wasn't able to find a way with applescript to bring in all the files, name the layers the same as the file names, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you'll need to specify the path to your desired folder as String.

If you take a look at the *updated code sample* below you'll notice that line 4 of your original code which read:

```js
prefs.sourceFolder = '/Volumes/SERVER_RAID/•Current/MPC';
```

has been changed to:

```js
prefs.sourceFolder = Folder('~/Desktop/targetFolder');
```

This now assumes the target folder is named `targetFolder` and it resides in your `Desktop` folder. You'll need to change the `'~/Desktop/targetFolder'` part as necessary to point to the folder you actually want. It also assumes you're running this on macOS as the shortcut to the Desktop folder (i.e. the `~/` part) will not be recognized on Windows.

---

**What are the other ways I can specify the path?**

1. You can specify path name using absolute paths such as:

   ```js
   prefs.sourceFolder = Folder('/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/targetFolder');
   ```

   *Note: This example actually points to the same folder as the first example. Assuming that the user is called John Doe of course!*
2. More info about setting file paths can be found [here](http://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/using-file-and-folder-objects.html#specifying-paths).

---

**What other changes were made to your code example:**

1. Lines 9 to 22 in your example code which read:

   ```js
   // prompt for source folder
   var sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog('Where are the Front and Back files?', Folder(prefs.sourceFolder));

   // ensure the source folder is valid
   if (!sourceFolder) {
      return;
   }
   else if (!sourceFolder.exists) {
      alert('Source folder not found.', 'Script Stopped', true);
      return;
   }

   // add source folder to user settings
   prefs.sourceFolder = sourceFolder;
   ```

   are now redundant. Instead, they have been replaced with the following snippet which will alert you if the folder you specified cannot be found:

   ```js
   // ensure the source folder exists.
   if (!prefs.sourceFolder.exists) {
     alert('Source folder not found.\n' + prefs.sourceFolder, 'Script Stopped', true);
     return;
   }
   ```
2. I added `main()` on line 30 below to invoke the `main` function. However, if you have that elsewhere in your code you can delete it.

---

**Updated code sample:**

```js
function main() {   
  // User settings
  var prefs = new Object();
  prefs.sourceFolder         = Folder('~/Desktop/targetFolder');
  prefs.removeFileExtensions = true;
  prefs.savePrompt           = true;
  prefs.closeAfterSave       = true;

  // ensure the source folder exists.
  if (!prefs.sourceFolder.exists) {
    alert('Source folder not found.\n' + prefs.sourceFolder, 'Script Stopped', true);
    return;
  }

  // Get a list of files
  var fileArray = getFiles(prefs.sourceFolder);

  // If files were found, proceed with your tasks.
  if (fileArray.length) {
    alert('I found image(s) in the specified folder\n' +
        'Now you need to write code to perform out a task :)');
   // <-- Continiue your code here
  }
  // otherwise, diplay message
  else {
    alert('The selected folder doesn\'t contain any recognized images.', 'No Files Found', false);
  }
}

main(); // <-- Invokes the `main` function

/**
 * getFiles - get all files within the specified source
 * @param {String} sourceFolder - the path to the source folder.
 */
function getFiles(sourceFolder) {
  // declare local variables
  var fileArray = new Array();
  var extRE = /\.(?:png)$/i;

  // get all files in source folder
  var docs = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  var len = docs.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var doc = docs[i];

    // only match files (not folders)
    if (doc instanceof File) {
      // store all recognized files into an array
      var docName = doc.name;
      if (docName.match(extRE)) {
        fileArray.push(doc);
      }
    }
  }

  // return file array
  return fileArray;
}
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I needed!! I had tried EVERY version of that except putting 'Folder' in front of the path. Thank you!! How do I 'close' this question? Thanks for all your help...